# Error al iniciar sesion con google con Flutter

Tags: flutter, sha1, google-signin

El caso es que soy nuevo en flutter, antes venia de Android Studio y todas esta cosas las hacia como si nada. En modo debug la app antes funcionaba, genere el SHA1 para meterlo en firebase... Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema vino cuando quise hacer la apk de la app que estoy desarrollando, y como os imaginareis no funcionaba. Visité varias paginas donde explicaban como solucionar este problema pero nada, de hecho ahora estoy pero porque no me inicia sesión ni en debug :(. ¿Alguna ayuda de algún experto?. La verdad es que no se que tocar más. Por si es de ayuda mi IDE es Visual Studio Code.

```dart
import 'package:TodosApp/Screens/profilescreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

import 'bottomNavBar.dart';

void main() => runApp(LoginPage());

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GoogleSignApp(),
    );
  }
}

class GoogleSignApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GoogleSignAppState createState() => _GoogleSignAppState();
}

class _GoogleSignAppState extends State<GoogleSignApp> {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googlSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
      content: new Text('Sign in'),
    ));

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googlSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    FirebaseUser userDetails =
        await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    ProviderDetails providerInfo = new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);

    List<ProviderDetails> providerData = new List<ProviderDetails>();
    providerData.add(providerInfo);

    UserDetails details = new UserDetails(
      userDetails.providerId,
      userDetails.displayName,
      userDetails.photoUrl,
      userDetails.email,
      providerData,
    );
    /*Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new ProfileScreen(detailsUser: details),
      ),
    );*/
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => new BottomNavBar(detailsUser: details)));
    return userDetails;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Image.network(
                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518050947974-4be8c7469f0c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
                  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.google,
                              color: Color(0xffCE107C),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                            Text(
                              'Sign in with Google',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => _signIn(context)
                            .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
                            .catchError((e) => print(e)),
                      ),
                    )),
                Container(
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.facebookF,
                              color: Color(0xff4754de),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                            Text(
                              'Sign in with Facebook',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    )),
                Container(
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.solidEnvelope,
                              color: Color(0xff4caf50),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                            Text(
                              'Sign in with Email',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserDetails {
  final String providerDetails;
  final String userName;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String userEmail;
  final List<ProviderDetails> providerData;

  UserDetails(this.providerDetails, this.userName, this.photoUrl,
      this.userEmail, this.providerData);
}

class ProviderDetails {
  ProviderDetails(this.providerDetails);
  final String providerDetails;
}
```

Y el error que me da es este:

`Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null))`

en esta linea--> `final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googlSignIn.signIn();`

Lo siento por no dejarlo con pantallazos pero soy nuevo en stackoverflow y totavia no manejo esto muy bien

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La mejor forma de explicarnos tu problema es incluyendo el código relevante.

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, he editado la pregunta añadiendo codigo, si me puedes ayudar me harias un gran favor y gracias de antemano

Comment: No conozco mucho de flutter, pero igual quería ayudarte a poner una pregunta que puedan responderte más fácil. Y por favor, no dejes de poner todo como texto. Como dice en los enlaces que te recomendé, hay que poner todo como texto y evitar al máximo las capturas de pantalla (a menos que sea muy necesario) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve buscando con `duckduckgo` para ver si a otros les pasaba lo mismo que a ti... y es muy frecuente últimamente! Me dice que no buscaste mucho por ahí para ver qué hacían otros jejeje.

Una opción es que revises lo que dicen en [este issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33393#issuecomment-510395178). Esencialmente refieren a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500). En ella hay varias respuestas con votos (que indica que resolvieron el error para *algunos*):

- Actualizar Google Play Services a la versión más reciente.
- Que el error 12500 se resuelve añadiendo un support email al proyecto en *project settings*. Abriendo el link `https://console.firebase.google.com/`, seleccionando el proyecto y abriendo la pestaña settings, indicando un email de soporte válido y reiniciando la aplicación.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Que hay que revisar: La SHA key correcta está guardada en la Consola Firebase; Descargar el último google-service.json; Último y más importante, guardar el OAuth consent en credentials del google api, pantalla OAuth.

Esta última es la que señalan en el issue, en 2019, así que puede ser relevante a tu caso. Lo que hacen es ir a esta página (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), seleccionar el proyecto correcto en la lista (esquina superior izquierda). Luego van a `Oauth consent screen`, indican el application logo, el link al application homepage y el link a aplication privacy policy (con el project.firebaseapp.com) y guardan los cambios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de eso reportan que les funciona.

Comment: El caso es que si que he hecho esos pasos, tengo seleccionado el correo, la clave sha1 puesta en firebase, la ultima version de google play services y la pantalla de consentimiento de OAuth. Ya no se que mas mirar...

Comment: @Aitroll si hiciste alguno de los cambios sugeridos, he visto en los comentarios que toma tiempo a que cargue los cambios :/ También, que si actualizaste Google Play Services, reinicies todo antes de volver a probar